# How to set ansible's gather_subset per host?

Tags: ansible

We can use `gather_subset` at play level.
Is it possible to use it on a per host level? Like putting it in a host_vars file?
My quick testing on 2.2.1.0 did not work out.

My problem at hand: I have a host, for which get_cpu_facts fails. And really, I never need hardware facts for this host, so I would like to put `"!hardware"` in its `gather_subset`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you can't set `gather_subset` per host if you use automatic fact gathering at play start.

But you can disable automatic fact gathering and call `setup` manually with required parameters (which can be supplied from host vars):

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  pre_tasks:
    - setup:
        gather_subset: "{{ gather_subset | default(omit) }}"
```

Comment: Wouldn't `pre_tasks` be even better?

Comment: Yes, if you use roles in the same play.

Comment: Would you mind changing your answer?

Comment: @Elrond updated